# SQL Server - Using Combined Column in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble using a combined column in my WHERE clause. I'm trying to combine two columns and do a WHERE x IN (a,b,c) to filter the rows.

Here's my data:

```
Tag      Param
------   -----
TI-123   LL
TI-123   LO
FI-321   LO
FI-321   BAD
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```
SELECT [Tag] + '.' + [Param] AS 'TagParam' 
   FROM Tags
   WHERE 'TagParam' IN ('TI-123.LL', 'TI-123.LO')
```

The results never match the WHERE clause and always come up empty. I could keep the rows separate and use WHERE with a lot of ANDs and ORs, but it's much harder to read. I'm going to have around 100 items in the IN() statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a table alias defined in a `SELECT` in the corresponding `WHERE`.  Putting single quotes around things just confuses the issue, turning things into string constants.

Repeat the expression:

```
SELECT ([Tag] + '.' + [Param]) AS TagParam
FROM Tags
WHERE ([Tag] + '.' + [Param]) IN ('TI-123.LL', 'TI-123.LO');
```

If you don't want to repeat the expression, you can use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join (the `apply` keyword).  But your expression is simple enough.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand it now. So the only way to use a column alias in a WHERE clause is to first have it returned as an actual column name?

Comment: @Ken . . . Exactly.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. let me answer some questions... Ha..Ha.. just for fun.. Super

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write that

```
SELECT [Tag] + '.' + [Param] AS 'TagParam' 
FROM Tags
WHERE Tag = 'TI-123'
  AND Param IN ('LL', 'LO')
```

This make it sargable (can use indexes).